# Perl how to introduce a text in front of a keyword(match) and keep the rest from a file

Tags: perl, splice

I am new to perl and I need to edit a text file by adding some text after i find a keyword(match), I need to save the changes in the same file but keeping all the old information, not overwrite anything.

The keyword (match) and the information I want to add will remain the same everytime even if the other data from the file will change.

```
To make a summary:

data that will change (not interested)

...

empty spaces < DATA >B506JGHD (< DATA > it would be the keyword(match) and i want to add for example 00000001 after it)

output that I need:empty spaces< DATA >00000001B506JGHD

...

empty spaces< DATA >J6443MNF

output:empty spaces< DATA >00000002J6443MNF

...


empty spaces< DATA >C89583F

output:empty spaces< DATA >00000003C89583F

...
other data (not interested)
```

and so on, it would be like 7 < DATA > in the file so I want to add 00000000 to 00000006 for each < DATA >.

I am looking for a simple solution if exists, I know that I probably need to read and go trough the text file find the keyword and rewrite everything but I am not sure how to do this.

```
What I tried so far is this:

use strict;
use warnings;

open FILE, "<FL_85E920795_Y060_H21_V001_E.odx" or die $!;
my @lines = < FILE >;
close FILE or die $!;

my $idx = 0;
my $string = '00000000';
do {
    if($lines[$idx] =~ /< DATA >/) 
        {
            splice @lines, $idx, 0, $string++;
            $idx++;
        }
    $idx++;
    } until($idx >= @lines);

open FILE, ">FL_85E920795_Y060_H21_V001_E.odx" or die $!;
print FILE join("",@lines);
close FILE;
```

but does not help me so much as my output is like this:
00000000 empty spaces < DATA >Info, if I try to move the data that I want in front of < DATA > it overwrites everything.

The first response that will work for me I will accept as a solution.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $counter = "00000000";
while (<>) {
   s{< DATA >\K}{ $counter++ }eg;
   print;
}
```

Usage:

```sh
fn=FL_85E920795_Y060_H21_V001_E.odx
the_script "$fn" >"$fn".new
mv "$fn".new "$fn"
```

`\K` "keeps" what was matched up to the `\K`, and thus replaces only the empty string that follows `< DATA >` with the value returned by the replacement expression.

---

As a "one-liner":

```sh
perl -i -pe'BEGIN { $c = "00000000" }  s{< DATA >\K}{ $c++ }eg' \
   FL_85E920795_Y060_H21_V001_E.odx
```

Comment: Maybe I did not understand correctly, I tried:

use strict;

use warnings;


my $filename = 'FL_85E920795_Y060_H21_V001_E.odx';

open(FH, '<', $filename) or die $!;

my $counter = "00000000";

while (<>) {

   s{< DATA >\K}{ $counter++ }eg;

   print;

}

close(FH);
But this only copies the text again without adding anything.
If I use > instead of < when I open the file, the file will be empty and all informations will be overwriten. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Desired result can be achieved with following demonstration code

NOTE:

- this solution reads whole file into memory
- if file is too big preferable approach would be read line by line

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $count = 0;
my $re_match = qr/< DATA >/;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

$data =~ s/$re_match/sprintf "%08d",$count++/ge;

say $data;

__DATA__
To make a summary:

data that will change (not interested)

...

empty spaces < DATA >B506JGHD (< DATA > it would be the keyword(match) and i want to add for example 00000001 after it)

output that I need:empty spaces< DATA >00000001B506JGHD

...

empty spaces< DATA >J6443MNF

output:empty spaces< DATA >00000002J6443MNF

...


empty spaces< DATA >C89583F

output:empty spaces< DATA >00000003C89583F

...
other data (not interested)
```

Output

```
To make a summary:

data that will change (not interested)

...

empty spaces 00000000B506JGHD (00000001 it would be the keyword(match) and i want to add for example 00000001 after it)

output that I need:empty spaces0000000200000001B506JGHD

...

empty spaces00000003J6443MNF

output:empty spaces0000000400000002J6443MNF

...


empty spaces00000005C89583F

output:empty spaces0000000600000003C89583F

...
other data (not interested)
```

Comment: Ikegami offers more elegant solution when `$counter` assigned value of `00000000` which allows to utilize `$count++` in place of `sprintf "%08d", $cont++` for substitute operation.

Comment: This removes `< DATA >` and adds a trailing blank line